# Use VB within Excel to open up a Word Doc and search and replace a string which is in a text box within the word document

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

When my code is executed from Excel, it will open up a Word document and can replace strings in the word doc with a given value taken from the Excel file, however it will not currently replace any text that is within a Text Box in the Word doc.

Here is my code (which I took from a previous post on here) -

```
For Each itm In arrNames
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Test.docx"
    With objWord
        .Activate
        With objWord.Selection.Find
            .Text = "Sheep"
            .Replacement.Text = itm
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 2
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute Replace:=2
        End With
    End With

    objWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\Users\Test\Desktop\ReportPage\" & itm & ".doc")         
Next itm
```

Are there additional arguments I need to pass into the With statement in order for text in a Text Box to also be replaced?

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the solution, here is the code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution.

Here is the code -

```
Dim objWord2 As Object
Set objWord2 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord2.Visible = True
objWord2.Documents.Open "C:\Users\kmccorma\Desktop\FRONTCOVER.doc"

'Iterate round a list of names
For Each itm In arrNames

    Dim rngStory As Word.Range

    'Iterate through all story types in the current document
    For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
      'Iterate through all linked stories
      Do

        Dim strText As String

        ' Get the text from the current TextBox
        strText = rngStory.Text

        'Check if the current text box contains the string you are looking for
        If InStr(1, strText, "SearchText") Then

            'Overwrite the text in the TextBox
            rngStory.Text = itm

        End If

        'Get next linked story (if any)
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next

    If itm & "X" <> "X" Then
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\Users\kmccorma\Desktop\FrontCover\" & itm & ".doc")
    End If

Next itm
```